# Measure Theory Specially Carathéodory measure. and the sigma algebra induced by that

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $X$ be a set, and let $T$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

Let $f: T \to [0,1]$ be a measure and
let $\mu∗ f$ be the Carathéodory outer measure induced by $f$. Is it always the case that $T = T\mu∗ f$?

I wonder if we could use the following fact:
you may freely use the fact that on the real line, there exists a Lebesgue measurable subset which is not Borel.

Comment: What is $T\mu*f$?

Comment: Does $T\mu * f = \{S \subseteq X \mid [\mu * f](S) \neq \infty\}$?

Comment: it means sigma-algebra of all measurable sets by μ∗f.


         μ∗f(A) =inf { sum of f(E)  : {E}  belongs to Covers of A)

Comment: The Question would be improved by incorporating that clarification into the body of the Question.  As you can see from @StubbornAtom's edit, it is possible to [post mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  You provided little in the way of *context* for the Question, and posts that only contain a problem statement (without context) may be closed for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. Let $T$ be a sigma-algebra which is not complete with respect to $f$ (there are plenty of examples, ranging from trivial to $B_{\mathbb{R}}$). The sigma-algebra of Caratheodory measurable sets is complete with respect to $f$.

Comment: Thank you so much.